# The ~ character is showing compilation error in snowflake

Tags: amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

unexpected '~'

When trying to migrate queries from red shift to snowflake, i keep on getting unexpected '~'.

Please help

case when tablename.fieldname ~'..'then .. else ..

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the `~` operator is Postgres specific. It is not a standard SQL operator.

If you're trying to use regex here's some general documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html

Or perhaps the LIKE/RLIKE functions
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html

If that's not what you're after, or I'm misunderstanding, can you provide more code, your expected results, and the full error message?

Comment: Thanks , just replaced ~ with RLIKE and it worked

Comment: great! Make sure to mark answers as correct if they helped! :)